# Extjs 3.4 Button fires n times

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button that fires some action such as 
    `someBtn.on('click'm function(..) { ... }`
and I did some arithmetic operation inside. I saw calculated numbers and it was wrong, so I used `console.log()` to track it and the action was being fired multiple times.

More specifically, I have a `window`, let's say A, that has multiple rows and when I click one of the rows another window, B, pops up and I can type numbers there. When I type numbers and click saves it does some works and hide B windows and I can click other rows on A to alter other rows.

When I click first time, B runs only once, and second time, it runs twice, third, three times .... 
I have been looking at my code but I have no idea how this can be happening.

**This is my code:**

```
function openCustDeposit(idCustomer) {

    require(['view/Deposit'], function (dep) {
        var windep= Ext.getCmp('windep');

        if (!windep) {
            windep= new Ext.Window({
                ...
                items   : [dep.initObj],
                plain   : true,
                closable: true,
                closeAction :'hide',
                ...
                listeners:{
                    show:function() {
                        this.loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(this.body, {
                            msg:'Loading. Please wait...'
                        });
                    },
                    destroy:function(){
                       if(this.mask)delete this.mask;
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            ....
        }
        ...
        windep.show();
        ...
        dep.store.load();

        dep.grid.custDepositPostBtn.on('click', function(obj,evt) 
        {
            try {
                var str_idCrdtMemo='', str_CRApply='', sumCRApply=0;
                var objGrid = grid;     
                var selRec = objGrid.selModel.getSelected();

                ....

                selRec.set('CustDeposit', sumCRApply);
                selRec.set('idPostCheck', str_idCrdtMemo.substr(0,str_idCrdtMemo.length-1));
                selRec.set('CustDeposit2', str_CRApply.substr(0,str_CRApply.length-1));
                ....
                closeWin(arCustDeposit.grid);       // window close
            }
            catch (e) { Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', e); }
            finally {
                ....
            }
        });
    });
}`
```

Any advice would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Post your code. It's likely you keep attaching a new handler to an existing button each time you display the dialog.

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening. Move the code that adds the listener inside `if (!winDep)`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I thought adding listener is inside? Isn't listener the one `listeners: { ...` inside of Ext.Window?

Comment: This: `dep.grid.custDepositPostBtn.on`